# Mouse Button click wont register

Tags: button, user-interface, unity-game-engine

```
var note : String = "blah"  

function OnGUI()
{

    if (IsPaused)
    {

        GUI.Box (Rect (580,20,100,210), "Pause");


        if (GUI.Button (Rect (590,130,80,20), "Info"))
        {
           Debug.Log("I pressed it");
           GUI.Button (Rect (450, 200, Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2), info);

        }


        else if (GUI.Button (Rect (590,160,80,20), "Quit")) 
        {

            Application.Quit();

        }



        else if(GUI.Button (Rect(590,190,80,35), "Back"))
        {

            IsPaused = false;

            GetComponent(LookAtMouse).enabled = true;

        }

}
```

This is my function for my GUI, as you can see, i have three buttons within it. The quit and back buttons work fine but when i click the info button, nothing will register.

I put `GUI.Button (Rect (450, 200, Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2), info);` This line of code outside the if statement to check if it works and it will but when its inside the statement i get nothing.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Bear in mind that the GUI is drawing in "immediate" mode: if you expect a button to show up in every frame, you will need to draw it every frame. Meanwhile, `GUI.Button` returns true only once when pressed. You might have better luck caching some boolean flag to control display of certain UI elements.

Comment: Please refrain from using offensive language in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var displayInfo : boolean = false;


 if (IsPaused)
        {

            GUI.Box (Rect (580,20,100,210), "Pause");


            displayInfo = GUI.Toggle(Rect (590,130,80,20), displayInfo, "Info");

            {
               if(displayInfo)
               {
                  GUI.Button (Rect (450, 200, Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2), info);
               }

            }
```

@rutter thanks for the idea, i used the boolean idea you had and created a toggle to check, if the info is displayed, create the instance of the textfield when it was toggled on